# How to mask a UIScrollView?

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, calayer, mask

I currently have an image mask I want to use to mask a UIScrollView.
The scrollview holds 1 UIImageView.

Here is what I do at the moment in viewdidload:

```
CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"ScrollMask.png"].CGImage;
mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 384);
[Scroll1.layer setMask:mask];
```

This works to some degree. 
It masks the ImageView inside the scrollview but not the scrollview itself.

Is there a way to mask the scrollview's CALayer and not imageview's layer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should put the UIScrollView into a UIView, and then apply the mask to the UIView instead of the UIScrollView.

```
CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"ScrollMask.png"].CGImage;
mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 384);

UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 384)];
[containerView.layer setMask:mask];

[containerView addSubview:Scroll1];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

Comment: How to apply gradient color mask to the boundary of container view?

Comment: @Rajesh Quoting from Apple's documentation: "The layer’s alpha channel determines how much of the layer’s content and background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow the underlying content to show through but fully transparent pixels block that content." All you need is a mask image with opaque to transparent gradient.

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341637/how-to-add-transparent-gradient-to-the-boundry-of-uiview-mask-image. This will explain my question.